# Left Sub Menu broken only on Mac Safari and Mac Chrome

Tags: html, css, submenu

http://cypresshh2.cakuun.com/index.php?id=4

I've rebuilt this a few times, to suit desired changes of the client. (Some of the CSS is a mess at this point.) The only problem is that the sub menu on the left does not work in Chrome for Mac or Safari for Mac. Works in all PC browser versions and works in FF for MAC.

On the broken browsers, you can see that the box apparently opens but falls behind the lower LI elements instead of bumping the LI elements down.

The sub menu is supposed to be open if the user is on the parent page or any of the sub pages.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is a bit of a mess as you say but here's a few things that seem to help whe I messed about with it in Firebug:

1. Change all your menu and sub menu 'a'a tags to be display:block and give them some padding.
2. Remove the height from your LI elements
3. Remove display:inline-block from the LI elements
4. Give your LI elements margin:0 0 10px
5. Remove display:block from sub-menu LI elements
6. Change the LI background position to '0 0' rather than just defining 'center'

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks... After re-arraging the site multiple times, the CSS is of course a mess. I'll be better off just yanking all of the pertinent CSS and doing as you say above. (I was praying for someone to find that 'silver bullet'.

Comment: @Brant - Did my CSS suggestions fix your issue?

Comment: It did, you can have a look now, works stellar. I ripped all the old CSS out and went at it again. Anchors are block'd now. I think the main culprit was the li.current was set with a static height among other things. But the piling on of multiple CSS rules during rebuilds was not the correct way to do things. Thanks again for your help!